# Changing ImageView Source Does not Change Properly Image of ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-imageview

Actually It is changing but into Blank!

In my App, i going to get my Images-Path from Database and show them in main activity. this process achieves by selecting thumbnails of images in DialogFragment and sending their Record ID to main Activity withing an Interface for Communicating between Fragment-Activity.
at this point i am going to use an Asynctask inner class to get FilePath of selected Image  and Show it to ImageView.

everythings works perfectly EXCEPT that the ImageView does not show it properly and it just show blank!

P.S.: the FilePath is Correct, i used it in onActivityResult on some place in app.

Thank you.

Main Activity code:

```
public class AnnotateDiagramActivity extends Activity implements Communicator {

 @Override
    public void respond(String data , int requestCode) {
        //Passing Project ID from CPDialogFragment or PLDialogFragment


        switch(requestCode) {

        case OPEN_PROJECTID:
            PROJECTID = Integer.valueOf(data);
            loadProject(PROJECTID);
            ToastShort(data);
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }


}

  public class loadMainImage extends AsyncTask<Project,Integer,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Project... params) {


        return project.GetFilePath();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute( String result) {
   //here is my main issue:

        fragmentView.setImageBitmap(new ImageDecoder().decodeFile(new File(project.GetFilePath())));

        fragmentView.postInvalidate();
    }

}

 public void loadProject(int ID)
{
    project = new Project();
    project= expertDbHelper.getProject(ID);
    SharedPreferences openedProject = getSharedPreferences("openedProject", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor projectEditor = openedProject.edit();
    projectEditor.putInt("id",project.GetID());
    projectEditor.putString("filePath",project.GetFilePath());
    projectEditor.commit();

    new loadMainImage().execute(project);
}

}
```

**EDIT For Verifying on Returning Image From File Path:**

```
 protected void onPostExecute( String result) {
        ImageDecoder imageDecoder = new ImageDecoder();
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        File file =new File(result); 
        if(file.isFile()) {
            bmp=imageDecoder.decodeFile(file,500);
            fragmentView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            fragmentView.postInvalidate();
        }
        else
        { Log.e("Async Task Is File: " ,String.valueOf(file.isFile()));}

    }
```

Comment: have you verified "new ImageDecoder().decodeFile(new File(project.GetFilePath()))" returns an image ?

Comment: i use this line of code on many place to get the image, but please let me check again

Comment: @DavidJhones i check this by changing OnPostExecute to this:

Comment: @DavidJhones:    protected void onPostExecute( String result) {
            ImageDecoder imageDecoder = new ImageDecoder();
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            File file =new File(result);
            bmp=imageDecoder.decodeFile(file,500);
            Log.e("Async Task Is File: " ,String.valueOf(file.isFile()));
            if(bmp !=null) {
                fragmentView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                fragmentView.postInvalidate();
            }
            else
            {Log.e("Async Error:" , "bmp");}

        }

Comment: @DavidJhones : and the result is the same , i verified that line of code returns an image

Comment: update your post without putting codes as comment dude :)

Comment: what do you get from this line "project.GetFilePath();" ? is it path of the image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74508/discussion-between-davidjhons-and-adnan).

Comment: Thanks to David Jhones we find that there is something with fragmentView so i need to go deep into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that my Image does not set properly due to some criteria that calculated from previous loaded image, so i check my code and find (layout boolean parameter) in my code that needs to be reset.

```
protected void onPostExecute( String result) {

        ImageDecoder imageDecoder = new ImageDecoder();
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        File file =new File(result);
        Log.e("Async Task Result: " ,result);
        if(file.isFile()) {
            bmp=imageDecoder.decodeFile(file,500);
            fragmentView.reset();
            fragmentView.recycle();
            fragmentView.layout= false;
            fragmentView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("Async Task Is File: " ,String.valueOf(file.isFile()));
        }

    }
```

Comment: @DavidJhones and Thanks to you without your help god knows when i can able to fix my issue